# how to install magento using amazon web server

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, installation

I Installed magento using Cpanel.

Now I have to install magento using "Amazon Web Server"

There is no cpanel in Amazon Web Server.

I am not that much familiar to install magento using commands.

please help me to install magento using "Amazon Web Server"

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have apache2 in Amazon AWS. When you define vhosts in apache2 you define a root directory for your web applications. Similarly we define root directory for nginx server too in nginx conf file. Now download the required version of magento and unzip that in your web root directory. Create a virtual hosts and point it to your magento directory. Also download magento sample database and restore in your MySQL. Now open it in your web browser and it will guide you through installation.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply. 

IS i have to use FTP [filezilla] access to transfer the files.

Can you please explain me in detail about this with steps.

Comment: Yes, you can use FTP to transfer the files. Or of you are comfortable with using scp, you can use even that.
You can create virtual hosts as described here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts